# How to clear Yahoo Mail recent searches

Tags: privacy, yahoo-mail

In the current version of Yahoo Mail, when you focus on the search field, a drop-down list appears with the latest searches made. Is it possible to clear this list? And if yes, how?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible by clicking on the “Clear” button in the search history drop-down.

[image]

Comment: I've noticed on some accounts this recent searches popup doesn't even come up when you give focus to the search box. Any idea why?